# How to work with libcamera framebuffer contents?

Tags: libcamera

1. If I specify a format like UYVY10, what is contained in framebuffer memory? Is it a packed raw bit stream of 10-bit numbers so I need to count the bits and byte-op them into machine usable integers? Or it is an array of uint16 that holds numbers with maximum value of 10-bit?
2. I can handle either `bufferCompleted` or `requestCompleted` event for frame processing. What is their difference? I just cannot imagine how it is ever possible to have one request with several buffers.